# Storing Output of Azure CLI command as variable

Tags: linux, bash, azure-cli

I need to store the output of an AZ cli commands that fetches my private IPs as a variable.

I am using the following in a bash script:

```
echo "Fetching Monitoring Server IP"
SERVER_IP=$(az vm show -n ${THIS_VM_NAME} -g ${RSC_GRP_NAME} --query privateIps -o tsv)
echo "$SERVER_IP
```

It would appear that this isnt working as when I echo the variable, it comes back empty.

```
+ THIS_VM_NAME=XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX
+ echo 'Fetching Monitoring Server IP'
Fetching Monitoring Server IP
++ az vm show -n XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX3 -g XXXX-XX-XX-XX-XX --query privateIps -o tsv
+ SERVER_IP=
+ echo ''
```

I will appreciate any pointers on this

Comment: Are you sure the command is writing to stdout? Try appending `2>&1` to your command to catch stderr as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**

The command you post lost a parameter to get the private IPs, you can use the command with the parameter `-d` or `--show-details` like this:

```
az vm show -g resourceGrouName -n vmName -d
```

But this command just gets all the IPs including the secondary IP.

You can get all the VM primary IPs of each interface through a shell script like this:

```
count=0
while : ; do
    nic=$(az vm nic list -g resourceGroupName --vm-name vmName --query [$count].id -o tsv)
    if [[ $nic == '' ]]; then
        break
    fi
    privateIps[$count]=$(az vm nic show -g resourceGroupName --vm-name vmName --nic $nic --query ipConfigurations[0].privateIpAddress -o tsv)
    let count++

done
echo ${privateIps[*]}
```

Comment: This is incorrect as my command is returning the private ip. Please run the command above to see if it works on yours

Comment: Oh, sorry. I made a mistake. I have updated the answer. And the command you post also missed a parameter. And there is something different in the two solutions.

Answer (score 5):

A solution to my similar problem in Azure Cloud Shell was putting a **dollar sign** before your SERVER_IP variable if **Powershell** in chosen.

```
$SERVER_IP=$(az vm show --name vmname --resource-group rgname --show-details --query [publicIps] --output tsv)
```